# Iterate over List of array objects

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Object[]> items = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    String [] item  = new String[5];
    item[0]="saurabh";
    item[1]="Kumar";
    item[2]="Singh";


    items.add(item);

    for(Object[] d:items){
        System.out.println(d.toString());
    }

}
```

I have this code where i want to iterate over list of array object ,but when i try i prints the hashcode.i know its wrong way but what could be the solution?

Comment: @Eran [Singh, null, null, null, null] i got this

Comment: @Eran thanks i got whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object[]> items = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        String [] item  = new String[5];
        item[0]="saurabh";
        item[1]="Kumar";
        item[2]="Singh";


        items.add(item);

        for(Object[] d:items){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
        }

    }
```

I tried this and got required output,thanks eran.

Answer (score 0):

Try this soultion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object[]> items = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        String [] item  = new String[5];
        item[0]="saurabh";
        item[1]="Kumar";
        item[2]="Singh";


        items.add(item);

        for(Object[] d:items){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
        }

    }
```